# Access CVS through Apache service using SSPI

Tags: python, apache, cvs, sspi

I'm running an Apache server (v2.2.10) with mod_python, Python 2.5 and Django.  I have a small web app that will show the current projects we have in CVS and allow users to make a build of the different projects (the build checks out the project, and copies certain files over with the source stripped out).

On the Django dev server, everything works fine.  I can see the list of projects in cvs, check out, etc.  On the production server (the Apache one) I get the following error:

[8009030d] The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized

I'm trying to log in to the CVS server using SSPI.  Entering the same command into a shell will execute properly.

This is the code I'm using:

```
def __execute(self, command = ''):
        command = 'cvs.exe -d :sspi:user:password@cvs-serv.example.com:/Projects ls' 
        p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
        return p.communicate()
```

I've tried a number of different variations of things, and I can't seem to get it to work.  Right now I believe that Apache is the culprit.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of SSPI make me think you are using CVSNT, thus a Windows system; what is the user you are running Apache into? Default user for services is SYSTEM, which does not share the same registry as your current user.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to mention I was on Windows XP.  I was trying to have Apache use the login of the computer it was running on, which would explain the SSPI auth error.  I'll see if I can get the service to run under another user.